# SQL Server are Worktable logical reads still 8k per page?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am giving a presentation in a few weeks and I have a query that I am going to tune that initially pushes all the rows from a table in the database into a Worktable to sort it into an appropriate order, as there is no index to support the query. The STATS IO gives the following:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 368495, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

I want to include a calculation to say how much memory is being used reading the Worktable. Working from 8k per page for a logical read would it be 8 * 368495 / 1024 (for MB) / 1024 (for GB) that is approximately  2.8GB.

Is the calculation correct or are the other things I need to consider?

I have tried to find an article that answers the question online regarding logical reads and worktables and can only find basic info on 8k per page for a logical read, so that's what I've been working too.

Comment: Consider that an 8k page in the work table could be read more than once so the number of worktable logical reads might not reflect its size and memory. Also, a worktable might not always be memory resident so it would be more correct to say "how much space" rather than "how much memory". I think you could use `sys.dm_db_task_space_usage` during query execution to examine the size of internal objects.

Comment: Hi Dan, I've checked the dmv you've suggested and read up on what it is showing me and it appears that it is using very limited space to create and use the work table. I will leave out the calculation and just focus on removing the table spool. Thanks for taking the time to reply.